# Embedded python: multiprocessing not working

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using Python 3.1.4 that is embedded as a scripting environment in an application(x64).
So far I have encountered a lot of limitations with the embedded python. I don't know if it is normal or if the programmers of the application have blocked some functionalities.

For example the following code isn't working:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()

# --> error in forking.py: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'
# print(sys.argv) gives the same error
```

`sys.executable` return the path to the application.

I've tried this as wel:

```
multiprocessing.forking.set_executable('C:\Python31\python.exe')
multiprocessing.set_executable('C:\Python31\python.exe')
```

Without success.

Is there a workaround possible ? It is very unlikely that I would have the leverage to make the developers of the application change something in their code.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I got it to work by adding the following:

`sys.argv = ['c:/pathToScript/scipt.py']`

I needed this line as well:

`multiprocessing.set_executable('C:/Python31/python.exe')`

Otherwise an other instance of the application open instead of running the code.

The only problem I have left is that I can't use the methods that control the application itself (like: create_project(), add_report(),..). My primary goal was to be able to call multiple methods without the need to wait for the first one to finish completion. But I think this is just not possible.

Comment: are you sure you don't mean to use threading instead of multiprocessing?

Comment: @ Ionut Hulub: I've problems as well with threading, something with the GIL I presume. That's why I tried with multiprocessing  
@ NPE: Windows 7, 64bit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, `sys.argv` is not available in embedded code:

> ## [Embedding Python](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html#embedding-python)
>
> The basic initialization function is Py_Initialize(). This initializes
>   the table of loaded modules, and creates the fundamental modules
>   builtins, __main__, and sys. It also initializes the module search
>   path (sys.path).
>
> Py_Initialize() does not set the “script argument list” (sys.argv). If
>   this variable is needed by Python code that will be executed later, it
>   must be set explicitly with a call to PySys_SetArgvEx(argc, argv,
>   updatepath) after the call to Py_Initialize()

On Windows, `multiprocessing` must spawn new processes from scratch. It uses a command line switch `--multiprocessing-fork` to distinguish child processes, and also transmits the original `argv` from parent to child.

Assigning `sys.argv = ['c:/pathToScript/scipt.py']` before creating subprocesses, like you discovered, 
would seem to be a good workaround.

A second relevant piece of documentation is that of [`multiprocessing.set_executable()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_executable):

> Sets the path of the Python
>   interpreter to use when starting a child process. (By default
>   `sys.executable` is used). Embedders will probably need to do some thing
>   like
>
> `set_executable(os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix, 'pythonw.exe'))` 
> before
>   they can create child processes. (Windows only)

Answer (score 1):

If it does not work, try to set **sys._base_executable = os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix, 'pythonw.exe')**

```
PyObject *msys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
PyObject *pyString = PyUnicode_FromWideChar(L"path/to/pythonw.exe", -1);
PyObject_SetAttrString(msys, "executable", pyString);
PyObject_SetAttrString(msys, "_base_executable", pyString);
Py_XDECREF(pyString);
```