# Python C API: Include "if __name__ == '__main__':" call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-c-api

I am on Windows and am using the Python 3 C API to import a library that uses the Python multiprocessing library.  Per the docs, on Windows I need put a main guard in place, like

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rest of code making calls into classes used multiprocessing
```

How do I create the main guard from C?  Is there a flag I can pass to Py_Initialize() ?  Is there another clever way to wrap the code in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` check?

Comment: Don't know the answer to your question, but can you just wrap your program in a `main` function, and run it in a Python module and use the guard? You can do that with `ctypes.CDLL(shared_library).main()`

Comment: I need to call Python as the C program reads data from hardware, so I can't think of a way to do that.  I need some way to wrap all the calls I make from C in the main gaurd.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636266/embedded-python-multiprocessing-not-working might be relevant.