# can't pickle <class 'module.class'> it's not the same object

Tags: c, multithreading, pyqt5, cython, pickle

Although there are a few answers for this problem but none of them worked for me.

I have a cython project which contains a class that does multi threading.

**cythonMod.pyx**:

```
class doThreadingStuff(Process):
    KillIt = False
    def __init__(self, to_emitter: Pipe, queue_from_mother: Queue, queue_to_mother: Queue, daemon=True):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        threading.Thread(target=wasupbrah, daemon=True, name="wasupbrah",
                                     args=(self.queue_to_mother,self.queue_from_mother, text,)).start()

def wasupbrah(queue_to_mother, queue_from_mother):
    print("[+] called wasupbrah")
    # do stuff

cdef public void mainCode():
    print("Running MainCode() here")
    if ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():
        #do PyQt Stuff
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

        mother_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()
        queue_to_mother = Queue()
        queue_from_mother = Queue()
        emitter = QtDesignerStuff.Emitter(mother_pipe, queue_to_mother, queue_from_mother)

        dThS = doThreadingStuff(child_pipe, queue_from_mother, queue_to_mother)
        dThS.start()
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to provide the full code, but I have provided the portion which I believe have the problem.

If you compile above using cython, it will generates a `cythonMod.pyd`, `cythonMod.c` and `cythonMod.h`, as well as making the `mainCode` function a public declaration, accessible to external C codes.

If I move the `mainCode` to say `runcythonMod.py` and run it as `python runcythonMod.py` it works perfectly.

Now, I have a C program that simply calls the `mainCode` function from the cython project as below:

**runcythonMod.c**:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "runcythonMod.h"
#include "nanalyzer.h"

//compile using: gcc -o runcythonMod.exe cythonMod.c cythonMod.c -IC:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -LC:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs -lpython39
int main(){
    printf("current PID %d\n", getpid());
    PyImport_AppendInittab("mainCode", PyInit_cythonMod);
    Py_Initialize();
    //PySys_SetPath("C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/python39/;.");

    PyObject *sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    PyObject *path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
    PyList_Append(path, PyUnicode_FromString("."));
    PyList_Append(path, PyUnicode_FromString("C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/python39/"));


    /* 1st: Import the module */
    PyObject* ModuleString = PyUnicode_FromString((char*) "commonmodules");
    if (!ModuleString) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Error formating python script\n");
    }

    PyObject* Module = PyImport_Import(ModuleString);
    if (!Module) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Error importing python script\n");
    }


    /* 2nd: Getting reference to the function */
    PyObject* Function = PyObject_GetAttrString(Module, (char*)"mainCode");
    if (!Function) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Pass valid argument to mainCode()\n");
    }

    printf("Good So far!\n");

    if(PyImport_ImportModule("mainCode") == NULL){
        printf("Failed to import mainCode\n");
    }
    __pyx_f_13cythonMod_mainCode();
    return 0;
}
```

**The problem** I believe is that pickle is complaining that `doThreadingStuff` is being called from `mainCode` function but not from my C's `main` function. Unfortunately, it is hard to call `doThreadingStuff` from my C code, because my cython have a PyQt5 process and shares the Pipe and Queue between the PyQt5 App and `doThreadingStuff`.

I tried creating a separate function to call `doThreadingStuff` as suggested by the web, but that didn't work either.

```
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'cythonMod.doThreadingStuff'>: it's not the same object as cythonMod.doThreadingStuff
```

```
def pickledoThreadingStuff(child_pipe, queue_from_mother, queue_to_mother):
    dThS = doThreadingStuff(child_pipe, queue_from_mother, queue_to_mother)
    dThS.start()


cdef public void mainCode():
    print("Running MainCode() here")
    if ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():
        #do PyQt Stuff
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

        mother_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()
        queue_to_mother = Queue()
        queue_from_mother = Queue()
        emitter = QtDesignerStuff.Emitter(mother_pipe, queue_to_mother, queue_from_mother)

        pickledoThreadingStuff(child_pipe, queue_from_mother, queue_to_mother)
```

Above didn't work either.

All responses are much appreciated.

Comment: The code you provide uses `threading`, but the error message comes from `multiprocessing`. They're not the same thing, and suggests that the example code you provide is irrelevant to the problem you're having. I don't think multiprocessing is ever likely to work for an embedded application (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636266/embedded-python-multiprocessing-not-working), and especially not one where modules are available only through inittab, since it relies on starting a new Python process

Comment: It would be helpful to understand why you're doing the above and for what purpose.