"process died unexpectedly" with cythonized version of multiprocessing code
This is an offshoot of this question. The code in python runs fine. When I tried the cythonized version, I started getting "Can't pickle <cyfunction init_worker_processes at 0x7fffd7da5a00>" even though I defined the init_worker_processes at top level. So, I moved it to another module and used the imported init_worker_processes. Now, I get the below error:
error: unrecognized arguments: -s -c from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(tracker_fd=8, pipe_handle=16) --multiprocessing-fork
Python3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:96: UserWarning: resource_tracker: process died unexpectedly, relaunching.  Some resources might leak.
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: process died unexpectedly, '


I'm not explicitly using -s or -c as reported in the error. The error is coming from below code in the multiprocessing library (method - ensure_running)
warnings.warn('resource_tracker: process died unexpectedly, '
                              'relaunching.  Some resources might leak.')


How to resolve this issue?
# updated Python code
# ---------------------- mp_app.py ------------------
import argparse
import logging
import signal
import sys
import time

import multiprocessing as mp
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Dict, NoReturn

import numpy as np

from mp_utils import init_worker_processes 


@dataclass
class TmpData:
    name: str
    value: int


def worker(name: str, data: TmpData) -> NoReturn:
    logger_obj = mp.get_logger()
    logger_obj.info(f"processing : {name}; value: {data.value}")

    time.sleep(data.value)


def get_args(logger: logging.Logger) -> argparse.Namespace:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="test MP app")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-m",
        "--max-time",
        type=int,
        dest="max_time",
        required=True,
        help="max timeout in seconds",
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "-j",
        dest="num_workers",
        type=int,
        default=1,
        required=False,
        help=argparse.SUPPRESS,
    )

    try:
        args = parser.parse_args()
    except argparse.ArgumentError as err:
        logger.exception(parser.print_help())
        raise err

    return args


def mp_app(options: argparse.Namespace, logger: logging.Logger) -> NoReturn:
    map_data: Dict[str, TmpData] = {
        key: TmpData(name=key, value=np.random.randint(1, options.max_time))
        for key in ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "PQR", "STU", "XYZ"]
    }

    with mp.get_context("fork").Pool(
        processes=options.num_workers,
        initializer=init_worker_processes,
    ) as pool:
        results = []
        for key in map_data:
            try:
                results.append(
                    pool.apply_async(
                        worker,
                        args=(
                            key,
                            map_data[key],
                        ),
                    )
                )
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                pool.terminate()

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        for result in results:
            try:
                result.get()
            except Exception as err:
                logger.error(f"{err}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_logger = logging.getLogger()

    try:
        args = get_args(main_logger)
        mp_app(options=args, logger=main_logger)
    except Exception as e:
        main_logger.error(e)
        raise SystemExit(1) from e

    sys.exit(0)

# --------------------- mp_utils.py --------------------------

import multiprocessing
import logging
import signal

from typing import NoReturn


def init_worker_processes() -> NoReturn:
    """
    Initializes each worker to handle signals
    Returns:
        None
    """
    this_process_logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
    this_process_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

Please note the main issue seems to be "-s" and "-c" being unrecognized option; not sure from where those are coming.
Edit-2:
While I'm still trying to decipher the cython build process as it happens through a complex make system in our environment. However, I'm guessing that I am able to trace the root cause of -s and -c options. -s seems to be coming from the _args_from_interpreter_flags method in subprocess.py (module subprocess).
In my python shell I see sys.flags as following -
>>> sys.flags sys.flags(debug=0, inspect=0, interactive=0, optimize=0, dont_write_bytecode=0, no_user_site=1, no_site=0, ignore_environment=0, verbose=0, bytes_warning=0, quiet=0, hash_randomization=1, isolated=0, dev_mode=False, utf8_mode=0, int_max_str_digits=-1)

Since sys.flags.no_user_site is 1, -s seems to get appended.
get_command_line in spawn.py seems to be adding -c. Since this branch is coming from else of if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False), is spwan approach not supposed to work with a cythonized binary?
EDIT-3:
I tried with both "fork" and "spawn". Both works in Python. But with cythonized build, "spawn" based app I get "UserWarning: resource_tracker: process died unexpectedly, relaunching.  Some resources might leak" message and along with "unrecognized arguments" for -s and -c. The cythonized version of the "fork" based app, simply hangs at launch itself as if it's waiting on some lock. I tried, pstack on the process id, but could not spot anything -
# top 20 frames from pstack
#0  0x00007ffff799675d in read () from /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff70c3996 in _Py_read (fd=fd@entry=3, buf=0x7fffbabfdbf0, count=count@entry=4) at Python/fileutils.c:1707
#2  0x00007ffff70ce872 in os_read_impl (module=<optimized out>, length=4, fd=3) at ./Modules/posixmodule.c:9474
#3  os_read (module=<optimized out>, nargs=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at ./Modules/clinic/posixmodule.c.h:5012
#4  os_read (module=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, nargs=<optimized out>) at ./Modules/clinic/posixmodule.c.h:4977
#5  0x00007ffff6fc444f in cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL (func=0x7ffff7f4aa90, args=0x7fffbae68f10, nargsf=<optimized out>, kwnames=<optimized out>) at Objects/methodobject.c:430
#6  0x00007ffff6f303ec in _PyObject_VectorcallTstate (kwnames=0x0, nargsf=<optimized out>, args=0x7fffbae68f10, callable=0x7ffff7f4aa90, tstate=0x419cb0) at ./Include/cpython/abstract.h:118
#7  PyObject_Vectorcall (kwnames=0x0, nargsf=<optimized out>, args=0x7fffbae68f10, callable=<optimized out>) at ./Include/cpython/abstract.h:127
#8  call_function (kwnames=0x0, oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=<synthetic pointer>, tstate=0x419cb0) at Python/ceval.c:5077
#9  _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (tstate=<optimized out>, f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3520
#10 0x00007ffff7066ea4 in _PyEval_EvalFrame (throwflag=0, f=0x7fffbae68d60, tstate=0x419cb0) at ./Include/internal/pycore_ceval.h:40
#11 _PyEval_EvalCode (tstate=tstate@entry=0x419cb0, _co=<optimized out>, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=<optimized out>, argcount=2, kwnames=0x0, kwargs=0x7fffbac0b750, kwcount=0, kwstep=1, defs=0x7fffbae95298, defcount=1, kwdefs=0x0, closure=0x0, name=0x7fffbae8d230, qualname=0x7fffbae8c210) at Python/ceval.c:4329
#12 0x00007ffff6f7baba in _PyFunction_Vectorcall (func=<optimized out>, stack=<optimized out>, nargsf=<optimized out>, kwnames=<optimized out>) at Objects/call.c:396
#13 0x00007ffff6f311aa in _PyObject_VectorcallTstate (kwnames=0x0, nargsf=<optimized out>, args=0x7fffbac0b740, callable=0x7fffbabefe50, tstate=0x419cb0) at ./Include/cpython/abstract.h:118
#14 PyObject_Vectorcall (kwnames=0x0, nargsf=<optimized out>, args=0x7fffbac0b740, callable=<optimized out>) at ./Include/cpython/abstract.h:127
#15 call_function (kwnames=0x0, oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=<synthetic pointer>, tstate=0x419cb0) at Python/ceval.c:5077
#16 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (tstate=<optimized out>, f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3506
#17 0x00007ffff7066ea4 in _PyEval_EvalFrame (throwflag=0, f=0x7fffbac0b5b0, tstate=0x419cb0) at ./Include/internal/pycore_ceval.h:40
#18 _PyEval_EvalCode (tstate=tstate@entry=0x419cb0, _co=<optimized out>, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=<optimized out>, argcount=2, kwnames=0x0, kwargs=0x7fffbac08f58, kwcount=0, kwstep=1, defs=0x7fffbae83b08, defcount=1, kwdefs=0x0, closure=0x0, name=0x7fffbae84830, qualname=0x7fffbae8c3f0) at Python/ceval.c:4329
#19 0x00007ffff6f7baba in _PyFunction_Vectorcall (func=<optimized out>, stack=<optimized out>, nargsf=<optimized out>, kwnames=<optimized out>) at Objects/call.c:396
#20 0x00007ffff6f311aa in _PyObject_VectorcallTstate (kwnames=0x0, nargsf=<optimized out>, args=0x7fffbac08f48, callable=0x7fffbabeff70, tstate=0x419cb0) at ./Include/cpython/abstract.h:118


I checked the cython build process prints something like following:
cython --3str --embed --no-docstrings -o mp_app.c mp_app.py
gcc -Os -Loss/Python3/lib -DNDEBUG -Wl,--strip-all -IPython-3.9.15/include/python3.9 -LPython-3.9.15/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu -LPython-3.9.15/lib -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lm -B /binutils/bin  -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -fPIC  -lpython3.9 mp_app.c -o mp_app.pex

PS: I've also edited the source code example

Please include a [mcve] with the relevant python and cython code you're using.

Added the python code

How are you using cython? The code you've posted works as expected for me on Python 3.9 (after adding the missing stdlib imports).

I'm still trying to decipher the cython build process as it happens through a complex make system in our environment. However, I'm guessing that I am able to trace the root cause of -s and -c options. -s seems to be coming from _args_from_interpreter_flags method in subprocess.py (module subprocess).

In my python shell I see sys.flags is following -



sys.flags
sys.flags(debug=0, inspect=0, interactive=0, optimize=0, dont_write_bytecode=0, no_user_site=1, no_site=0, ignore_environment=0, verbose=0, bytes_warning=0, quiet=0, hash_randomization=1, isolated=0, dev_mode=False, utf8_mode=0, int_max_str_digits=-1)
Since sys.flags.no_user_site is 1, -s seems to get appended.




get_command_line in spawn.py seems to be adding -c

Is spawn not supposed to work with cythonized binary?

I'm not sure, but you could try fork and see if that does anything different.

Actually, the example code does not work (hangs) on my system if I use fork (i.e. do not use spawn

It's still pretty unclear what you've actually done: have you taken the Python program shown and converted it into an executable using Cython? So that you're no longer calling Python directly but instead calling your executable?

I've updated the original post further. Yes, I'm directly calling the executable - no more call to Python directly.

There's definitely a long list of complications for multiprocessing and embedded programs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636266/embedded-python-multiprocessing-not-working. There's also a small amount of info in the Cython documentation although treat it as background info about the problem not a solution.

I was able to resolve the issue by switching to the fork start method from the spawn start method. Additionally, I had to move the worker method from mp_app.py to mp_utils.py as otherwise in the cythonized version it was throwing PicklingError for cythonized function worker.
I am still not sure why the spawn start method did not work for me on CentOS7 machine.
The final code is approximately following:
# ------------- mp_app.py ------------------
import argparse
import logging
import signal
import sys


import multiprocessing as mp
from typing import Dict, NoReturn

import numpy as np

from mp_utils import (init_worker_processes, worker_task, InterProcessData)


def get_args(logger: logging.Logger) -> argparse.Namespace:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="test MP app")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-m",
        "--max-time",
        type=int,
        dest="max_time",
        required=True,
        help="max timeout in seconds",
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "-j",
        dest="num_workers",
        type=int,
        default=1,
        required=False,
        help=argparse.SUPPRESS,
    )

    try:
        args = parser.parse_args()
    except argparse.ArgumentError as err:
        logger.exception(parser.print_help())
        raise err

    return args


def mp_app(options: argparse.Namespace, logger: logging.Logger) -> NoReturn:
    map_data: Dict[str, InterProcessData] = {
        key: InterProcessData(name=key, value=np.random.randint(1, options.max_time))
        for key in ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "PQR", "STU", "XYZ"]
    }

    with mp.get_context("fork").Pool(
        processes=options.num_workers,
        initializer=init_worker_processes,
    ) as pool:
        results = []
        for key in map_data:
            try:
                results.append(
                    pool.apply_async(
                        worker_task,
                        args=(
                            key,
                            map_data[key],
                        ),
                    )
                )
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                pool.terminate()

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        for result in results:
            try:
                result.get()
            except Exception as err:
                logger.error(f"{err}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_logger = logging.getLogger()

    try:
        args = get_args(main_logger)
        mp_app(options=args, logger=main_logger)
    except Exception as e:
        main_logger.error(e)
        raise SystemExit(1) from e

    sys.exit(0)


# ---------- mp_utils.py -----------
import time
import logging
import signal
import multiprocessing
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import NoReturn


@dataclass
class InterProcessData:
    name: str
    value: int


def worker_task(name: str, data: InterProcessData) -> NoReturn:
    logger_obj = multiprocessing.get_logger()
    logger_obj.info(f"processing : {name}; value: {data.value}")

    time.sleep(data.value)


def init_worker_processes() -> NoReturn:
    this_process_logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
    this_process_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

